# PHPMyAdmin is not working on appserv

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Yesterday my local Appserv worked normally. But today when I open my AppServ - PhpMyAdmin gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in C:\AppServ\www\phpMyAdmin\error.php on line 63

How can I solve this?

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` has nothing to do with mysql. Check if your php configuration has changed on server.

Comment: I'cant Open The > My Sql > !!

Comment: Okay, have fun then.

Comment: Listen to @Inurosen. `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is a PHP and not MySQL issue. Contact your host and see if your PHP config or version has changed. It seems your PHP build isn't supporting this func.

Comment: what do you mean my Host ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be issue with the your PHP/MySQL Configuration.

Please make sure you have proper version of PHP / MYSQL running and you should not have any issue.

Ideally you should have php 5.6.x version and mysql 5.6 running.

Comment: i'have PHP Script Language Version 6.0.0-dev
MySQL Database Version 6.0.4-alpha